# Typescript file stopped getting transpiled post Angular 9 upgrade with esnext module

Tags: angular, angular9

I have a typescript file (git-version.ts) at the root location of my project which is used in the Jenkins CI pipeline to read the latest commit/revision which triggered the CI build (it uses ts-node to run this ts file). Below is the glimpse of my project structure:

```
root
 |_src/
 |_angular.json
 |_git-version.ts
 |_package.json
 |_tsconfig.json
```

Earlier it used to work perfectly fine with Angular 7 but seems to be broken with the deafult esnext module loader of Angular 9. When I changed my module to 'commonjs' in current angular 9 tsconfig settings, it works absolutely fine. But, then I lose the advantage of differential loading feature as the commnjs tends to create one single bundle for my entire app. So, I had to switch back to 'esnext'. Below is my current tsconfig.json settings:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  }
}
```

I also tried changing the extension of the said ts file to js, but then it started to throw another exception, *"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"*. Apparently, I need a way to load this ts file using 'commonjs' and still use 'esnext' for the rest of the entire app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file in question is outside your src folder and it works fine with commonjs as you've mentioned, most likely it seems a problem with the typescript imports.

You can define a different loader for a specific file if you are willing to load a typescript file using ts-node. Something like this:

```
ts-node -O '{\"module\": \"commonjs\"}' git.version.ts
```

You can add it as an npm script and use it inside the Jenkinsfile for your CI pipeline.

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you so much @Mayuree.
I have added an npm script in package.json and used it in Jenkinsfile just before initiating the build, and it is working as expected.